# No Source Code is available for type java.text.SimpleDateFormat: GWT Compilation Error

Tags: java, gwt

I was trying to make a GWT application. Then I got some errors when using SimpleDateFormat class in ***client and shared side***.

```
[ERROR] [gwtfirst] Line 381: No source code is available for type java.text.SimpleDateFormat; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

following is my code in client side:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Window.alert(sdf.format(usersList.get(30).getCreatedate()));
```

But I can use SimpleDateFormat with server side...
I'm wondering if I can't use SimpleDateFormat in client or shared side?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not available in GWT. Use [com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) instead.

Comment: @tibtof you're right. Just a little addition for Mozzan - you CAN use SimpleDateFormat on the server side. Just not on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

GWT does not contain SimpleDateFormat instead it have DateTimeFormat
So you can use

```
 DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("YYYY/MM/DD") 
 Date date = dateTimeFormat.parse(str);
```

for more read "com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat".

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if that is the problem with my code though, because it has been working all day until now. I never changed that code... just stopped compiling....